# Grails spring security grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames

Tags: grails, spring-security

Lets say that i would like to utilize two authentication provider for the same login request.

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [
    'customAuthenticationProvider',
    'ldapAuthProvider',
    'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
    'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']
```

The scenario is that i first get authenticated with my customAuthenticationProvider, which grants/deny access. When this is done, it moves on to check if it is able to authenticate the user towards an LDAP server which in its turn grant/deny.

Is this the way that spring security will operate given for example the list of providerNames above? Or will it grant access if the first provider access/deny and behave accordingly.

Does all authentication attempts need to pass in order to be granted access?

Answer (score 5):

The providers will be tried in the order listed until one authenticates successfully, or they all fail. When one authenticates, the process stops, and the remaining providers will not be tried.